# SQL Developer - SELECT statement with AVG calculation displaying multiple averages?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, average

I'm trying to write a SELECT statement that averages a player's raw score, subtracts the raw score from the basis of 200, and then multiplies that by 90% to calculate the player's handicap.

This code seems to be applying the calculations correctly, but is creating many different averages, for every player.

```
SELECT BOWLERID "Bowler ID", b.BOWLERFIRSTNAME || ' ' || 
   b.BOWLERLASTNAME "Bowler Name",
   AVG(bs.HANDICAPSCORE)+ -200 * 0.90 "Handicap"
FROM BOWLER_SCORES bs
   JOIN BOWLERS b USING (BOWLERID)
GROUP BY BOWLERID, b.BOWLERFIRSTNAME, b.BOWLERLASTNAME, 
   bs.HANDICAPSCORE
ORDER BY bs.HANDICAPSCORE DESC;
```

I think it's a problem with my table join setup but I can't quite pinpoint it.

I'm very new to SQL, so any advice and pointers are much appreciated.

EDIT:

So in removing bs.HANDICAPSCORE and changing ORDER BY to "Handicap", I see now that the average calculations are incorrect. Also I need to round to no decimal points.

UPDATED CODE:

```
SELECT BOWLERID "Bowler ID", b.BOWLERFIRSTNAME || ' ' || 
   b.BOWLERLASTNAME "Bowler Name",
   AVG(bs.HANDICAPSCORE)+ -200 * 0.90 "Handicap"
FROM BOWLER_SCORES bs
   JOIN BOWLERS b USING (BOWLERID)
GROUP BY BOWLERID, b.BOWLERFIRSTNAME, b.BOWLERLASTNAME
ORDER BY "Handicap" DESC;
```

Do I have my AVG statement setup correctly?

Comment: Take off the bs.handicapscore in the group by and see if that helps.

Comment: Don’t use handicapscore in the group by

Comment: And do `ORDER BY "Handicap" DESC`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your calculation should be (200 - average) * 90% so

```
SELECT BOWLERID "Bowler ID", b.BOWLERFIRSTNAME || ' ' || b.BOWLERLASTNAME "Bowler Name", (200 - AVG(bs.HANDICAPSCORE)) * 0.90 "Handicap"
FROM BOWLER_SCORES bs
JOIN BOWLERS b USING (BOWLERID)
GROUP BY BOWLERID, b.BOWLERFIRSTNAME, b.BOWLERLASTNAME
ORDER BY "Handicap" DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the *`AVG()`* function, but you are also including the field in the `GROUP BY`.  In addition, I think your calculation is off, due to operator precedence:

```
SELECT BOWLERID as "Bowler ID", b.BOWLERFIRSTNAME || ' ' || b.BOWLERLASTNAME as "Bowler Name",
       (200 - AVG(bs.HANDICAPSCORE)) * 0.90 as Handicap
FROM BOWLER_SCORES bs JOIN
     BOWLERS b 
     USING (BOWLERID)
GROUP BY BOWLERID, b.BOWLERFIRSTNAME, b.BOWLERLASTNAME
ORDER BY AVG(bs.HANDICAPSCORE) DESC;
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(200 - AVG(bs.HANDICAPSCORE)) * 0.90`?

Comment: @digital.aaron . . . That does better fit the description.  I wonder why the OP has the subtraction in the wrong direction?